# Can I reassign an integer within the code?

Tags: python

I'm doing a homework in Anaconda:
My question is if can I reassign an integer, for example:

```
def vol(rad):
    for num in range(rad):
        num = 1  #I don't know if I'm doing fine assigning the number one or 
                 #should i do it other way.
        pi = 3.1416
        num += num ** 3 #trying to elevate the num integer to the 3rd potent
        rad = 3/4 * (num * pi)
    return rad
```

Once I run it, is just using the number one and I need to know the way to reassign it to use other values once running the function.
Hope you can understand my point and help me.
Thanks in advance.
The code is to calculate the volume of a sphere by the way.

Comment: instead of `num=1` put `print(num)` and you will see that `for num in range(rad)` assign different values to `num`

Comment: I suspect you want `num = num **3` (not +=).

Comment: shouldn be `return 4/3 * pi * (rad**3)` ?

Comment: Also the formula calls for `4/3`, not `3/4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see your for loop, you have `for num in range(rad):`, which means that `num` variable will take values from `0` to `rad-1`, but if you do `num=1` you will reassign that variable.
In addition, you are also reassigning the variable `rad` which you are using in your for loop range in `rad = 3/4 * (num * pi)`
Also `num += num **3` means you are doing `num = num + num**3`, whereas I assume you should be doing `num = num ** 3`
If I understand correctly, and the commentors also pointed out, you need to calculate volume of the sphere with radius `rad`, you don't need a for loop for this, you can simply do

```
def vol(rad):

      pi = 3.1416

      #Take cube of radius
      rad = rad ** 3  # trying to elevate the num integer to the 3rd potent

      #Calculate volume
      volume = (4 / 3) * (rad * pi)

      return volume
```

Now the output will be

```
print(vol(4))
#268.0832
print(vol(8))
#2144.6656
```

As an extra tidbit, we already have a way to get value of pi using `math.pi`

```
In [18]: import math                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [19]: print(math.pi)                                                                                                                                                                                               
3.141592653589793
```